# What should I do to improve my answer when it is deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I posted my first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676270/how-to-call-save-image-as-feature-in-chrome-extension/22691617#22691617) ever in Stackoverflow. I'm not sure exactly why it was deleted, but I still tried to enrich it after the deletion.

Now,

- What else should I edit or add to make my answer proper?
- What should I do next?
- Will it notify the moderators to just edit the answer without doing anything else? (At least this post cannot be undeleted, so I don't know what else can I do)

Comment: Your post was probably deleted due to being little more than a link initially. That said, you seem to have improved it significantly since then; this automatically puts it in a queue for review. If enough users feel the answer has been fixed, it will be undeleted.

Comment: The meta effect -- your answer is undeleted!

Comment: Bookmarking, as I'll refer anyone confused about how to write a great answer right here.

Answer (score 8):

This was [the answer you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/eb3b6258-d61b-40ab-a285-3af1ed5a36b1/view-source) in the first instance:

> I have the same question as you, but I have an alternative to do this:
>   use `chrome.downloads.download` api.
>
> But still I want to know a perfect answer to the question, like what I
>   also asked here:
>   [Does chrome extension api support downloads directly from browsing cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691443/does-chrome-extension-api-support-downloads-directly-from-browsing-cache)

This seems more to be of a question than an answer.  It would have collected at least 5 flags indicating that it is not an answer before it was deleted by a moderator.

Ensure that you *attempt* to answer a question when you post an *answer*.  DO NOT seek clarifications or ask another question when posting an *answer* and chances are that it wouldn't be deleted<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 Unless the post is deemed to be a spam.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! A very clear explanation!